# Notify ObservableCollection changed with nested objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, nested, observablecollection

I have a class `FamilyItemVM` which is used to bind to a `TreeView` source. This class is used in a main view model. I would like to know when the `FamilyItemVM` has changed (i.e. add or remove children in the UI).

**Main VM :**

```
public class FamilyVM : ObservableRecipient
{
    private ObservableCollection<FamilyItemVM> myFamilies;
    
    public FamilyVM()
    {
        myFamilies = new ObservableCollection<FamilyItemVM>();
        Families.CollectionChanged += FamilyCollectionChanged;
        BuildTree();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FamilyItemVM> Families // the property binded to the Treeview
    {
        get { return myFamilies; }
    }

    private void BuildTree()
    {
        //... the method which populate myFamilies property recursively
    }

    private void FamilyCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Here I want to know when something has changed (only add and remove items) in the whole object 
    }
}
```

**Items Class:**

```
public class FamilyItemVM : ObservableObject
{
    FamilyItemVM myParent;

    public FamilyItemVM(FamilyItemVM parent)
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<FamilyItemVM>();
        myParent = parent;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FamilyItemVM> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when an item is added or removed in the UI, how to notify each parent to finally notify the main VM in `FamilyCollectionChanged` method.

Comment: What notifications are you expecting to see? ObservableCollection only notifies when items are added / removed from the collection, not when properties of items change.

Comment: Indeed, it's my question, I want to know when an item is added or removed somewhere in the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current design, each `FamilyItemVM` only knows its parent `FamilyItemVM`. Therefore changes need to be notified upwards your family item tree. This can be done with an event that is raised whenever an `Items` collection changes. In fact, this is exactly what an [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-6.0) does with its [`CollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.collectionchanged?view=net-6.0) event. You can reuse the same parameter type, too, which is [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs?view=net-6.0). The difference is that we need to propagate the event all the way up to the root item.

The following apprach exposes an event `DescendantsChanged`, which notifies that any `Items` collection anywhere down the hierarchy changed. Each `FamilyItemVM` listens for its own `Items` collection changes by handling the `CollectionChanged` event. If any `FamilyItemVM` is added, a handler for its own `DescendantsChanged` event is added. This handler simply reacts to any descendant changes and raises the `DescendantsChanged` of its own instance, the parent of the current `FamilyItemVM`, to notify its own parent.

Let us review what happens at this point using this mechnism:

1. Any `FamilyItemVM` observes its `Items` collection.
2. An item is added, which triggers the `CollectionChanged` event.
3. A handler for the `DescendantsChanged` event is added to the item.
4. The `DescendantsChanged` event on the current instance (parent of the new item, `this`) is raised.
5. The parent of the parent which listens for the `DescendantsChanged` event (added in 2.) gets its handler invoked, reacts to it and raises its `DescendantsChanged` event the same way to notify its parent (see 4.).
6. This goes on, until there is no parent anymore, `_myParent` is `null`.

The last point with `null` is an **assumption** from the code you provided, I will explain later.

```
public class FamilyItemVM : ObservableObject
{
   private readonly FamilyItemVM _myParent;

   public FamilyItemVM(FamilyItemVM parent)
   {
      _myParent = parent;
      Items = new ObservableCollection<FamilyItemVM>();
      Items.CollectionChanged += OnItemsChanged;

      // If the Items collection can be reassigned (has a setter), remove this and the child handlers again.
      // Otherwise there may be a memory leak. This must be triggered from the setter.
   }

   public ObservableCollection<FamilyItemVM> Items { get; set; }

   // An event to notify that ANY of the descendent Items collections changed.
   public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler DescendantsChanged;

   private void OnItemsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      // Add the handler to any new VM that is added.
      if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
      {
         foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
         {
            var descendantFamilyItemVm = (FamilyItemVM)newItem;
            descendantFamilyItemVm.DescendantsChanged += OnDescendantsChanged;
         }
      }

      // Remove the handler if a child is removed to prevent a memory leak.
      if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
      {
         foreach (var oldItem in e.OldItems)
         {
            var descendantFamilyItemVm = (FamilyItemVM)oldItem;
            descendantFamilyItemVm.DescendantsChanged -= OnDescendantsChanged;
         }
      }

      // You should handle other collection changed actions, too, e.g. Reset.
      // ...

      // React to changes of this Items collection.
      // ...

      // Notify that descendants have changed.
      DescendantsChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
   }

   private void OnDescendantsChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      // React to any of the descendants having their Items collection changed.
      // ...
      var familyItemVm = (FamilyItemVM)sender;

      // Notify parent that any of its descendants changed its Items collection.
      // The sender here is the descendant that originally raised the event.
      DescendantsChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
   }
}
```

Now, from your code, I **assume** that the topmost items that are added to `myFamilies` in the `FamilyVM` have `null` passed as `parent` in the constructor, because you cannot pass `FamilyVM`. This means, that the `FamilyVM` is **not** notified.

To solve this issue, you can simply add your `FamilyCollectionChanged` method as handler to the `DescendantsChanged` event when building the tree in `FamilyVM`. But be aware that you have to add the handlers to the root items before adding further children, otherwise you will not get notified at this point.

```
private void BuildTree()
{
   // ...code to build the root items.

   foreach (var familyItemVm in myFamilies)
      familyItemVm.DescendantsChanged += FamilyCollectionChanged;
      
   // ...even more code to add the the children.
}
```

Comment: Clear and efficient! Thanks!